# Prove that $\Bbb P[\max_{k\le n}\bf {x}_k>\sqrt{(2-)\log n}$ as $n\to \infty$ $]=1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $\bf x_1,\bf x_2$, etc. be independent with common density $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Prove that $\Bbb P[\max_{k\le n}\bf {x}_k>\sqrt{(2-)\log n}$ as $n\to \infty$$]=1$.

I tried to use Borel-Cantelli lemam, but first I need to construct a $B_n$ that occurs infinitely often is equivalent to $\max_{k\le n}\bf{x}_k$$>\sqrt{(2-)\log n}$. But I am having trouble in finding such $B_n$. Could someone kindly help? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M_n=\max_{k\le n}X_k$. Using independence

$$P\{M_n\le x\}=\prod_{k\le n}P\{X_k\le x\}=\left[\Phi(x)\right]^n$$

For $0<\epsilon<1$ and $m$ s.t. $(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2\ln n}\ge 1$ for $n\ge m$ we have (using the lower bound for the tail of normal dist. $^{(*)}$)

$$
\sum_{n\ge m}P\{M_n<(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2\ln n}\}\le \sum_{n\ge m}\left[1-\frac{n^{-(1-\epsilon)^2}}{4(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{\pi\ln n}}\right]^n
$$
$$
\le \sum_{n\ge m}\exp\left\{-\frac{n^{\epsilon(2-\epsilon)}}{4(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{\pi\ln n}}\right\}<\infty
$$

because the summand can be bounded by $\exp\{-n^\delta\}$ for $n$ large enough and some $\delta>0$. Now the first Borell-Cantelli lemma implies that

$$\liminf\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{\ln n}}\ge \sqrt{2}\text{ a.s.}$$

---

$^{(*)}$ For $x\ge 1$

$$1-\Phi(x)\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{2x}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am confused about the inequalities. In my textbook, I am supposed to use the mill's ratio, which is $\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}<\frac{1}{\lambda \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\lambda^2/2}$, which is different here.

Comment: @Sherry: I added the required inequality

Comment: I notice there are several versions of mill's ratio. The one you used is equality. However, I have difficulty in applying the one in my textbook, which is inequality. When I apply the inequality, the inequality changed from $\le$ to $\ge$. Could you please help look at this?

Comment: The one in my textbook says $\int_{\lambda}^\infty \frac{e^{x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}<\frac{1}{\lambda \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\lambda^2/2}$, does this inequality have opposite direction with (*)?

Comment: @Sherry: $^{(*)}$ inequality is true for $\lambda\ge 1$. You can easily check that. (and yes, it has the opposite direction)

Comment: Thanks! I checked that. It is right. One more question, why we can replace $e^{-2\ln n (1-\epsilon)^2/2}$ by $n^{-(1-\epsilon)^2}$. Could you please help explain? I tried taylor expansion it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sherry: $e^{-(1-\epsilon)^2\frac{2\ln n}{2}}=e^{\ln n^{-(1-\epsilon)^2}}=n^{-(1-\epsilon)^2}$